# How do I know if humidistat is working?

Tags: humidifier

Is there a way to test an Aprilaire humidistat to see if it works? I switched out the solenoid and it still does not work.

Comment: are you talking about a humidistat or about a humidifier? ... which of those does not work? ... how do you know that it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a whole house humidifier: ***While the furnace is running***, gradually turn the humidistat up.   The solenoid should
'snap' on, opening the valve and water should start to flow...assuming someone hasn't turned the water off.   Turning the hummidstat back down should shut off the water flow.